# pass a parameter into a javascript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I saw the code as below in a html file. It appears like passing into the app.js a value as v=$appVersion

```
  <script>document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='resources/js/app.js?v=" + appVersion + "'><\/script>");</script>
```

However, I did not find a global variable "v" in app.js. Curious what does this line do...

Comment: this is likely a cache busting technique at play.

Answer (score 3):

This is for cachebusting. The `v=1231231` makes the script url unique, so that when a new version is released, the url changes, and the browser requests the new version instead of using the old cached one.

Answer (score 0):

If you add query parameters to any URL, the browser considers it as a different URL. You can fool the browser in case you need to circumvent caching.

If some URL has failed or blocked, adding query parameters to the URL will force the browser to retry the request for the same resource. Adding some random query parameters is mostly harmless unless of course if the same query parameter is being used or verified by the server/host/API you're hitting.